# Sort pandas dataframe by multiple columns using custom compare functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to sort a pandas dataframe with respect to multiple columns, where for ***some*** of the columns ("col2" and "col3") I want to use this custom defined compare function that takes two elements:

example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1,2,3], "col2": [[2], [], [1]], "col3": [[1,0,1], [2,2,2], [3]]})

>>> df
   col1 col2       col3
0     1  [2]  [1, 0, 1]
1     2   []  [2, 2, 2]
2     3  [1]        [3]
```

```
def compare_fn(l1, l2): #list 1 and list 2 
    if len(l1) < len(l2):
        return -1 # l1 is of smaller value than l2
    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        return 1 # l2 is of smaller value than l1
    else:
        for i in range(len(l1)):
            if l1[i] < l2[i]:
                return -1
            elif l1[i] > l2[i]:
                return 1
    return 0 # l1 and l2 have same value
```

now, I would like to sort with respect to all 3 columns, where in `col2` and `col3` the function used to compare two elements that I want used is my custom defined function. (for col1 it's a straightforward sort).

I tried:

`df.sort_values(["col1", "col2", "col3"], key=[None, compare_fn, compare_fn])`, this returns a `'list' object is not callable` error.

`from functools import cmp_to_key; df.sort_values(["col1", "col2", "col3"], key=[None, cmp_to_key(compare_fn), cmp_to_key(compare_fn)])`, this returns a `'list' object is not callable` error.

I even tried disregarding the first column all together and passing one argument to the key:
`df[["col2", "col3"]].sort_values(["col2", "col3"], key=cmp_to_key(compare_fn))` returns `TypeError: object of type 'functools.KeyWrapper' has no len()`

and

`df[["col2", "col3"]].sort_values(["col2", "col3"], key=compare_fn)` returns `TypeError: compare_fn() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l2'`.

So i know that at least one of my problems is not knowing how to use a two-element compare function for sorting a pandas DataFrame column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key function needs to take the whole series as the input.

Rewrite your function like this:

```
def compare_fn(l): #list 1 and list 2 
    return [(len(x), tuple(x)) for x in l]

(df.sort_values('col1')
   .sort_values(['col2','col3'], 
                key=compare_fn, kind='mergesort')
)
```

Output:

```
   col1 col2       col3
1     2   []  [2, 2, 2]
2     3  [1]        [3]
0     1  [2]  [1, 0, 1]
```

---

**Update** Also we can rewrite the function so as it works for other columns:

```
def compare_fn(l): #list 1 and list 2 
    return ([(len(x), tuple(x)) for x in l]
                if type(l[0]) == list       # case list
                else l                      # case integer
           )

df.sort_values(['col1','col2','col3'], key=compare_fn)
```

Comment: brilliant! Multiple calls to the sort_values function deals with the problem of applying the custom based sorting on select columns, and reframing the 2-elemnt compare function to a key function seems to work this way. I'll do more testing to confirm. I didn't know python sorting of tuples works this way.

Comment: @ZaidGharaybeh also see updated answer for another version of the function.

Comment: ```[ins] In [63]: y
Out[63]: 
[[1, 2, 3, 4],
 [],
 [10, 10],
 [1],
 [2],
 [3],
 [300000],
 [300000],
 [300000],
 [100, 1],
 [1, 100],
 [1, 2]]

[nav] In [64]: sorted(compare_fn1(y))
Out[64]: 
[(0, ()),
 (1, (1,)),
 (1, (2,)),
 (1, (3,)),
 (1, (300000,)),
 (1, (300000,)),
 (1, (300000,)),
 (2, (1, 2)),
 (2, (1, 100)),
 (2, (10, 10)),
 (2, (100, 1)),
 (4, (1, 2, 3, 4))]
``` i defined a list `y` and applied your function on it, it seems to be working perfectly. Sorry for garbled code but comments cant have proper spacing.